# perl regex for variable substitution

Tags: regex, perl

I want to substitute variables marked by a "#" and terminated by a dot or a non-alphanumeric character. 
Example: Variable #name should be substituted be "Peter"

```
abc#name.def => abcPeterdef
abc#namedef  => abc#namedef
abc#name-def => abcPeter-def
```

So if the variable is terminated with a dot, it is replaced and the dot removed. Is it terminated by any non-alphanum character, it is replaced also.

I use the following:

```
s/#name\./Peter/i
s/#name(\W)/Peter$1/i
```

This works but is it possible to merge it into one expression?

Comment: If you're really doing Perl variable substitution then you may want to look at [`String::Interpolate`](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Interpolate) which makes perl's own run time double-quote string interpolation code available. That way you can use `$s = 'abc$name-def'` or `$s = 'abc${name}def'` and then do the interpolation after setting `$name = 'Peter'`.

Answer (score 3):

There are several possible approaches.

```
s/#name(\W)/"Peter" . ($1 eq "." ? "" : $1)/e
```

Here we use `/e` to turn the replacement part into an expression, so we can inspect `$1` and choose the replacement string dynamically.

```
s/#name(?|\.()|([^.\w]))/Peter$1/
```

Here we use `(?|` `)` to reset the numbering of capture groups between branches, so both `\.()` and `([^.\w])` set `$1`. If a `.` is matched, `$1` becomes the empty string; otherwise it contains the matched character.

Comment: The first of a series of alternations that matches will be used, so `(?|\.()|(\W))` is fine.

Comment: @Borodin Yeah, but I feel `[^.\w]` is more explicit and robust. E.g. there's no way my regex will start matching in unexpected ways if someone embeds it in a bigger context.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
s/#name(?|\.()|(\W))/Peter$1/i
```

**Details**

- `#name` - matches the literal substring
- `(?|\.()|(\W))` - a [**branch reset group**](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3F%7Cpattern)) matching either of the two alternatives:

  - `\.()` - a dot and then captures an empty string into `$1`
  - `|` - or
  - `(\W)` - any non-word char captured into `$1`.

So, upon a match, `$1` placeholder is either empty or contains any non-word char other than a dot.

Comment: @melpomene We can work around it using `s/#name(?|\.()|(\W))/Peter$1/i`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using either a literal dot or a word boundary for the terminator

Like this

```
s/#name(?:\.|\b)/Peter/i
```

Here's a complete program that reproduces the required output shown in your question

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

for my $s ( 'abc#name.def', 'abc#namedef', 'abc#name-def' ) {

    ( my $s2 = $s ) =~ s/#name(?:\.|\b)/Peter/i;

    printf "%-12s => %-s\n", $s, $s2;
}
```

#### output

```
abc#name.def => abcPeterdef
abc#namedef  => abc#namedef
abc#name-def => abcPeter-def
```

Comment: Oh, neat. You could even do `#name\b\.?`.

Comment: @melpomene: I didn't spot that. I've been working backwards from `#name(?:\.|(?=\W))` but only got half-way!

Comment: @Melpomene: `s/#name\b\.?/Peter/` is nice!